# How can we create filtered lookup field in SharePoint 2010 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create a lookup column programmatically that filter some some values. In SharePoint 2010 out of the box it will show all the values from lookup list. I know there are third party tools implemented to support this. .

Answer (score 1):

Try [FilteredLookup](http://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/). It is custom field type, can be created programatically. It is basically a combobox so it does not handle lot of items (>1000) very well.